# How to add a heading at the top of node/add or node/edit?

Tags: 7, nodes

In my `node/custom_content/edit` and/or `node/add/custom_content` page I want to place a heading at the top of the page as "*Create New My-Content*".

Seems simple enough, but I am unable to do so. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to change the title of the page you can do this. This will make all node add form titles "Create new [content type]" instead of "Create [content type]".
It doesn't change the edit form because it doesn't make sense to put "new" in the title there because it is not new content, you are editing existing content.

Create a new custom module that implement this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MODULE_NAME_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // For the node add form.
  if (!$form['nid']['#value']) {
    // Add "new" to the page title.
    $node_types = node_type_get_names();
    drupal_set_title(t('Create new @type', array('@type' => $node_types[$form['#node']->type])));
  }
}
```

Comment: this works only for admin not for authenticated users

Comment: Are you sure about that? Try clearing the drupal cache.

Comment: yes...i did that...no effect

Comment: Using that same code it works for me for user 1, a regular authenticated user and anonymous users. - As you can see by looking at the code there is nothing in there that restricts things based on the user. - There must be something else in your set-up that is interfering. Maybe some other custom module code or your theme.

Comment: yes even i think so...the code is correct and looks good....thanks

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to answer this question is to enable the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) module, and create a custom rule that looks like so:

```
{ "rules_show_new_article_link" : {
    "LABEL" : "Show New Article link",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert" : [], "node_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : { "node" : [ "node" ], "type" : { "value" : { "article" : "article" } } } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Click \u003Ca href=\u0022[site:url]node\/add\/article\u0022\u003Ethis link\u003C\/a\u003E to add another article ..." } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some details about this rule:

- **Rules Events**: After saving new content or After updating existing content.
- **Rules Condition**: Content is of type `article`.
- **Rules Action**: Show a message on the site, whereas the actual message content that will be shown is "Click this link to add another article ..." and with 'this link' being rendered as an hyperlink to relative path `node/add/article`.

If you have the Rules UI enabled, you can just import the above rule in your own site. Adapt content type `article` to `custom_content` (or whatever fits your needs).

With that, each time you edit or create a node of article, you'll get such  message (with appropriate link) in the Drupal message area. Obviously, you could add any applicable rules logic to further improve this prototype (e.g. to only show this for selected user roles).

PS: this rule is my favorite sample to get started with the Rules module.